# Microsoft Graph REST API Error AADSTS65001 on access token request with live accounts

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

I'm using microsoft Grap API to sign users in on my web app and get their basic profile. I've followed every steps on [the microsoft overview](https://graph.microsoft.io/docs/overview/overview).

With any live email (tried outlook.fr and hotmail.com), I got this error while requesting for the access token:

```
AADSTS65001: No permission to access user information is configured for 'MyAppId' application, or it is expired or revoked.
```

Is there something I am missing ? I have configured only one permission on my Azur Portal app, under the microsoft graph api delegated permisions : "Sign in and read user profile". No other app authorization.

And when I try with an office365 account, everything works fine. I could even call `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me` and get the result.

I have checked my redirect_uri and they are matching on both the authorization and access token request. I have turned the APPLICATION IS MULTI-TENANT option ON and modified the manifest file, other than that everything is by default.

Can the microsoft graph api handle live sign in to my web app ? If so, can anyone help me understand where I am wrong ?

Here are my authorization link that works fine with any account :

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=MyClientId&redirect_uri=MyUri
```

And here is my access token request link :

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token
POST data : grant_type=authorization_code&code=MyCode&client_id=MyClientId&client_secret=MySecret&resource=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2F&redirect_uri=MyUri
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to be able to use Live Id / Microsoft Accounts in addition to Azure Active Directory accounts please use the new converged authorization flow as described in https://graph.microsoft.io/docs/authorization/converged_auth.

Instead of registering your app via Azure Portal you'll need to use https://apps.dev.microsoft.com and instead of statically declaring delegated permissions for your app it will be able to dynamically request permissions using a scope query parameter when requesting a token or code from https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will have to wait a stable version then !